# Mongoose - querying by comparing attributes of a document

Tags: mongodb, find, mongoose

is it possible to do a query in which I compare the attributes of each document?

For example:

Collection:

```
{
a
b
}
```

Query:

```
Collenction.find({ {a: { $lt: b}}).exec...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find({ $where : "this.a < this.b" })
```

This query is not performant. Or 
While inserting the document, insert a boolean true/false based on (a < b ) or ( b < a ) and query for that boolean.

Comment: thanks, but actually the query is more complex, I have to call also a function. It's something like this:

collection.find({ $where : "this.a < fun(this.b)" })

Maybe mongoose doesn't understand that fun is a function because of the quotes... Any other hints?

Comment: mongoose don't have to understand about 'fun'. It is the mongodb server which interprets this query. For using function in $where, check this doc : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/

Comment: Is it possible to pass a parameter to the function() ?

`db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return (this.credits == this.debits) } } );`

Comment: don't know about passing params in $where, but you can optionally choose to write a stored function in mongod server in system.js collection, and can call that function with parameters from client side, using eval command.